# Is there any relationship between an SVM classifier performance and the distribution of the dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

Do the accuracy and performance of an SVM classifier have a relationship with the distribution of a dataset? For instance if the dataset is distributed uniformly, how does it affect the performance of an SVM model? Moreover, which SVM kernel does suit a uniformly distributed dataset well?